# How is my NAS accessible from outside the network?

Tags: networking

A few years ago I bought a WD My Cloud (network attached storage), which comes with the ability to log on to their website from anywhere and read from/write to the NAS. I am confused as to how this is done.

I'm guessing they have some sort of DDNS set up to combat the lack of a static IP. But, I never set up any port forwarding to the NAS. So, how is it possible to access that specific device from outside the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same principle as how you can browse a web site: when a connection is initiated from inside your network, then hosts outside the network can send return traffic.

Your NAS is opening a connection to the cloud. When you use the cloud, then you can use to connection back to your NAS.

This is how many IoT devices work. It is also a big security problem as evidenced by the recent DDoS attack that used compromised IoT devices.